# Using Libsvm in Matlab for rainfall Prediction

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm, prediction

I am using SVM to predict rainfall. My data has 7 inputs- temperature ,humidity etc. My data is already normalized. problem is my accuracy comes out as 0. I dont understand whats the problem. Mean squared error = 0.00268152 (regression)
Squared correlation coefficient = 0.288652 (regression)

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;
load t5;
load lab;
[f g]=size(t5)
t9=transpose(t5);
[f1 g1]=size(t9)
train_data=t9(1:1300,:);
[f2 g2]=size(train_data)
train_label=lab(1:1300);
[f3 g3]=size(train_label)
Model1=svmtrain(train_label,train_data,'-s 4 -t 0 -h 0 -c 8 -g 2');
test_data=t9(1301:1453,:);
[f4 g4]=size(test_data)
test_label=lab(1301:1453);
[f5 g5]=size(test_label)
[y, acc]=svmpredict(test_label,test_data,Model1);
```

Please tell me what's the problem

Comment: Why do you think accuracy can't be 0?

Comment: what does your lab consist of? What are the values? And what's your training accuracy?